# Get pathname along with PHP vars using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to save an entire URL paths to a variable, including the php vars, eg:

```
mysite.com/pagename?id=2
```

I can use

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

but this only retrieves the URL without the variables.

Is there a function to retrieve the URL as a literal string?

Comment: it's hard. this answer explains how to get the query parameters in javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter

Comment: store this link in your bag of tricks [parsing-urls-with-the-dom](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

`window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried see if it works:

```
document.URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
//  Get current page url using JavaScript
var currentPageUrl = "";
if (typeof this.href === "undefined") {
    currentPageUrl = document.location.toString().toLowerCase();
}
else {
    currentPageUrl = this.href.toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/498368/Get-current-page-URL-using-JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

It's hard , [this answer explains how to implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) from the top response:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

//var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
//alert(query.foo);
```